# How to get Google+ ID of a person

Tags: javascript, google-plus

Is it possible to get the google+ id of a person using his emailadres with javascript?

Comment: I'd check the Google Plus API for something corresponding to you problem. But quickly checking it, I found nothing that would help. https://developers.google.com/+/api/

Comment: I also checked the Google Plus API but i couldn`t find any solution also! Thank you for your profile!

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no API for Google+ that allows you to look up a user's profile ID from their email address.